# Full size background for sections in Susy grid

Tags: css, background, grid, susy-compass

I want to create something like this in the [Susy grid system](http://susy.oddbird.net):

[image: Website layout]

The different color demonstrate different sections of the website and also their background colors. The vertical lines are the grid columns.

If I use a simple grid container I can set the background color only within the div which is inside the grid, but I would like to have the background color stretched to the left and right edge of the website. The content stays inside the grid.

I found a solution using multiple grid containers (one for each section), but I heard that this approach is not recommended.

And I also don't want to use a fluid grid container.

Comment: Where did you hear the multiple-container approach wasn't recommended? I highly recommend it. There are other options using generated content and negative margins, but I find them all a bit flakey compared to simply having multiple containers.

Comment: _"@include container mixin will apply the susy grid scoped to that container so you can actually have multiple grids on a page but I do not recommend this."_ ← found in [this Susy introduction](http://scottdavis.github.io/blog/2011/12/30/introduction-to-building-websites-using-susy-and-compass-vertical-rhythm/).

And there is also no mention in the Susy reference, so I was a little bit confused whether this approach is correct.

But if you say, it's no problem to use multiple containers, than it's fine.

Comment: Oh, I see you are the developer of Susy, so I can take your advice seriously! :-)

Comment: Yeah, there are several problems with his statement. :) Susy doesn't actually apply or scope a grid to anything. The "grid" is really just a concept that we use to do math - it never exists anywhere. The container mixin just applies a max-width (with clearfix and a few other little helpers). You can ignore it altogether, and use Susy anywhere you like. Susy just breaks down any available space *as though* it were the grid you defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric Meyer, a developer of Susy, pointed out in the comments, the Susy grid is just a concept and there is nothing wrong with having multiple grids on the website, one in each section.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar issue.
I had used the following approach: Have a `div` (let's call it 'content') inside each of your sections.

Apply the container class to the 'content' div. `.content{@include container;}`
This way, when you set the background color of a section, it spans the entire width of the page while the content in the sections adheres to the rules of the grid.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: That's actually exactly the solution I was using.